# Error in ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, types

I am getting continuously an error on `ExecuteNonQuery();`. I have tried many ways but don't know where I am wrong.

I am using `float` data type in orderid, price, quantity, discount, order price columns in SQL Server.

Kindly help.

```
string query = "Insert into  dbo.orders (OrderType,Product_Name,Product_Category,Product_Quantity,Product_Price,Date,Discount) values(@txt_rdvalue,@cb_oname,@cb_ocat,@cb_oqty,@txt_oprice,@Date,@txt_disc)";

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_rdvalue.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb_oname.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb_ocat.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb_oqty.Text))
{
    lbl_incorrect.Text = "please fill up all the fields";
    lbl_incorrect.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Pizza Mania;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_rdvalue",txt_rdvalue.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_orderid",txt_orderid.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_oname", cb_oname.SelectedText);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_ocat", cb_ocat.SelectedText);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_oqty", cb_oqty.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_oprice", (txt_oprice.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_disc", txt_rdvalue.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date));

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
        }
    }
}
```

The error message I am getting:

> The parameterized query '(@txt_rdvalue nvarchar(8),@txt_orderid
>   int,@cb_oname nvarchar(40' expects the parameter '@cb_oqty', which was
>   not supplied

Comment: You are only checking 

`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_rdvalue.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb_oname.Text) || 
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb_ocat.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb_oqty.Text)`

But there are other four values.You need to ensure that all are not null values.Otherwise these type of exception will be thrown.

Comment: Tag dbms product! (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: Your `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` and `cmd.Connection = con;` lines are unnecessary by the way. Also open your connection _just_ before you execute your command.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: If you use `float` for those columns, why you send them `string`? Try to parse _those_ strings to `double` and pass them as a value.

Comment: how to check date like in a code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yes i have done it. The convert to double thing works 
thankyou all 
Appriciated.[enter link description here][1]



cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_rdvalue",txt_rdvalue.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_orderid",Convert.ToDouble(txt_orderid.Text));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_oname", cb_oname.SelectedText);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_ocat", cb_ocat.SelectedText);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_oqty", Convert.ToDouble(cb_oqty.SelectedValue));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_oprice",Convert.ToDouble((txt_oprice.Text)));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_disc",Convert.ToDouble(txt_disc.Text));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date));


  [1]: http://www.stackoverflow.com/alygorejaanswers
```

Answer (score 0):

You are providing **@txt_orderid**(`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_orderid",txt_orderid.Text);`) parameter which doesn't exists.Check your code once again.

If it's **`autoincrement`** coloumn why are you providing this.

Also datatype mismatching is happening.

Comment: i am providing this because it is incrementing from another table in db

Comment: What are the datatypes of the coloumns?

Comment: It may be due to the Datatype mismatching of coloumns.

Comment: ordertype nvarchar(50
)

Comment: ordertype nvarchar, orderid bigint, productname nvarchar(max)

Comment: product_category nvarchar(50) , product price,quantity,discount are float

Comment: convert the values or parse getting from the textboxes ,before using them as parameters.How can you store string values in floating type coloumns.Parse them as double execute your program.

Comment: i have changed float to nchar but that doesnt work
suggest me the datatype kindly

Comment: You don't need to change the datatypes in database.Parse the values getting from textboxes as double and execute your insert query.